# $\mathbb{Z}$ as argument of hyperlink fails

Tags: hyperlink, mathbb

`$\mathbb{Z}$` (from amsfonts) causes an error as first argument in `\hyperlink{}{}`,
but not as second argument:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage[hyperindex]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linktocpage=true,colorlinks}

\begin{document}
Works: Integers \protect\hyperlink{link:$Z$}{$Z$} 

Works: Integers \protect\hyperlink{link:$Z$}{$\mathbb{Z}$}

%Fails: Integers \protect\hyperlink{integers $\mathbb{Z}$}{$Z$} 

\end{document}
```

gives an error message when I uncomment the next-to-last line: `Undefined control sequence. \GenericError ... #4 \erhelp \@err@...` How can I avoid this?

This issue arose while writing a macro that links keywords from the main text into the index, using the keyword as both first and second arguments of a hyperlink. I'd like this to work no matter what the keyword is.

Comment: the first argument is a _name_ like `\label` it shouldn't have any formatting so math or `\mathbb` or anything.

Comment: Real quick: There's nothing unusual about `\mathbb` not "working" in the first argument of `\hyperlink`: `\mathbf`, `\mathsf`, `\mathfrak`, `\mathcal`, etc in the first argument of `\hyperlink` don't "work" either...

Comment: if you really want to you could use `\hyperlink{\detokenize{integers $\mathbb{Z}$}}{integers $\mathbb{Z}$}` but it seems like a misuse.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! The workaround with \detokenize did work for the problem posed; but when I then made a NewDocumentCommand containing that \hyperlink line, I ran into problems again - from which I concluded that I should heed your advice and avoid \mathbb inside a hyperlabel altogether.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote,

> `$\mathbb{Z}$` (from `amsfonts`) causes an error [when used] as first argument in `\hyperlink{}{}`. ... This issue arose while writing a macro that links keywords from the main text into the index, using the keyword as both first and second arguments of a hyperlink. I'd like this to work no matter what the keyword is.

I think the following candidate solution may raise further problems down the line,[*] but "robustifying" the macro name used in the first argument of `\hyperlink` (and `\hypertarget`...) -- be it `\mathbb` or, say, `\mathcal` -- seems gets the job done. More generally, if a "keyword" isn't "robust" to begin with, make it robust by running `\robustify` on it.

A general comment: This approach would appear to be a second-best (or even third-best!) solution. Far better would be not to use any macros or any "active" characters (such as `$`) in the first argument of `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget`.

[*] TeXperts will probably point out good reasons for not using `\robustify` the way it's employed here...

---

Here's a full MWE. `\hypertarget` sets the "targets", and `\hyperlink` provides "links" to the targets established by `\hypertarget`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for '\mathbb'
\usepackage[hyperindex]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linktocpage=true,colorlinks}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % for '\robustify' macro
\robustify{\mathbb}
\robustify{\mathcal}

\begin{document}
\hypertarget{$Z$}{Target: $Z$}

\clearpage
\hypertarget{$\mathbb{Z}$}{Target: $\mathbb{Z}$}

\clearpage
\hypertarget{$\mathcal{Z}$}{Target: $\mathcal{Z}$}

\clearpage
\hyperlink{$Z$}{link to $Z$}

\hyperlink{$\mathbb{Z}$}{link to $\mathbb{Z}$}

\hyperlink{$\mathcal{Z}$}{link to $\mathcal{Z}$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico: thanks for the robustify tip, \robustify{\mathbb} did solve the stated problem. But mysteriously it did not work for \robustify{\mathbbm} from the bbm family.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: yes, the links in Micos code do work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - My first MWE was lacking the corresponding `\hypertarget` statements. That's fixed in the updated MWE.

Comment: The first argument to `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` should be a label valid in a URL. Maybe those links work, but are not portable.

Comment: @egreg - I fully agree with your view that the first argument of `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` should satisfy the requirements of `\label`. Note that I'm only claiming that the `\robustify` trick "works" for `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget` -- I definitely wouldn't recommend actually using this trick...

Comment: @jvd - The `bbm` package was last updated in 1999; it uses the directive `\DeclareMathAlphabet` to set up `\mathbbm`. In contrast, the `amfonts` package (which provides `\mathbb`) employs `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet`. I honestly can't say I understand the difference between these two directives. However, the latter would seem to be just a bit more robust (or amenable to robustification) than the former. As David and Enrico (and I) have already commented, it's *not* a good idea to use macros in the first argument of `\hyperlink` (and `\hypertarget`). Do find a way to achieve your objectives.

Comment: @Mico Thanks to all for the expert advice. I've now set up the `\xindex{text}{index}` command that I'm building in such a way that 'text' is printed to the MainText and 'index' to the Index, hyperlinked with hyperlabel=text via `\hyperlink{text}{text}` and `\index{index@\protect\hypertarget{text}{index}}`. Thus, `\mathbbm` and friends are forbidden inside 'text' but allowed inside 'index', e.g. `$\mathbbm{Z}\xindex{is the set of integers}{integers, $\mathbbm{Z}$.`